# How to properly rename/refactor a x:Key Directive in WPF?

Tags: wpf, resources, key, resourcedictionary, directive

Topic says everything I think. If Visual Studio itself is not able to rename a resource maybe a third party tool like Resharper is able to do that?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with Quick Replace ?

Comment: @franssu: You would need to check every replacement manually, unless you take the risk of replacing things by accident. There are good reasons for tools like ReSharper spending a lot of effort developing proper renaming functionality that considers the context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReSharper has a function for renaming WPF Resources:

[image: ReSharper]